# How do I move an image into a cell in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell, cell-array

I built a 1*5 cell named N and need to copy an image (img)matrix into each entry in it what should I do? This is what I came up with but it doesn't work....
I'm trying to avoid for loops so my code will be faster.

```
function newImgs = imresizenew(img,scale)  %scale is an array contains the scaling factors to be upplied originaly an entry in a 16*1 cell
    N = (cell(length(scale)-1,1))'; %scale is a 1*6 vector array
      N(:,:) = mat2cell(img,size(img),1); %Now every entry in N must contain img, but it fails
    newImgs =cellfun(@imresize,N,scale,'UniformOutput', false); %newImgs must contain the new resized imgs 
end
```

Comment: **1:** don't avoid loops until you've written the loop code and found it is too slow. MATLAB is no longer slow with loops, and any process you apply to an image will take way more time that looping over a set of images in a cell array. **2:** `cellfun` is an M-file function that uses a `for` loop, so you're not avoiding loops. **3:** It is more important that your code is readable and maintainable, forget fast unless you don't meet time requirements (e.g.: I need to graduate in 3 years and this code will take 5 years to complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood from your question, and agreeing with Cris Luengo on the loop part, here is what I would suggest. I assume, that `scale(1) = 1` or something like that, because you initialize `N = (cell(length(scale) - 1, 1))'`, so I guess one of the values in `scale` is not important.

```
function newImgs = imresizenew(img, scale)

  % Initialize cell array.
  newImgs = cell(numel(scale) - 1, 1);

  % Avoid copying of img and using cellfun by directly filling 
  % newImgs with properly resized images.
  for k = 1:numel(newImgs)
    newImgs(k) = imresize(img, scale(k + 1));
  end

end
```

A small test script:

```
% Input
img = rand(600);
scale = [1, 1.23, 1.04, 0.84, 0.5, 0.1];

% Call own function.
newImgs = imresizenew(img, scale);

% Output dimensions.
for k = 1:numel(newImgs)
  size(newImgs{k})
end
```

Output:

```
ans =
   738   738

ans =
   624   624

ans =
   504   504

ans =
   300   300

ans =
   60   60
```